# Is there a Keyboard shortcut on windows to kill a process when black screen and task manager won't even come up?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, task-manager, kill

Sometimes some games crash, but the screen stays black; alt-tab, ctrl-alt-del and ctrl-shift-esc don't wrok and the only option I have is to shutdown the PC (I have windows 10 now, when I had 8 usually ctrl-alt-del worked and I could kill the process with task manager). Is there in windows a shortcut to kill the current process?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-Alt-Del is **the** shortcut key to get out of a process, so if that fails there isn't any additional secret backup key. It means your system is completely locked up. But black screens are not typical ways for a PC to fail, so this might be an issue w/ your video driver or your video card overheating. Make sure you have the latest version of you video card driver and always keep it updated. Also try providing more ventilation for your video card. If it always fails after a while of playing, it's probably overheating causing it.

Comment: it's not a problem about overheating or whole system crash. The system is still responsive as the mouse can be moved and when I click the power button (no force shutdown) the game closes and I can see the ctrl-alt-del screen just before the normal shutdown screen occurs. GPU is always stable at 60°-65°

Comment: This means it's either a bug in the game or your video card driver. Is your problem specific to just one game?